# How to generate random sample of size 80 with specific split ratio in R?

Tags: r, split, sample

I would like to generate a random sample of size `80` whose elements are either `1` or `2`. I want `70%` `1` and `30%` `2`. 
How can I do that in R?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sample` by specifying the `prob`

```
sample(1:2, 80, prob = c(.7, .3), replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need a deterministic ratio instead of a probabilistic one, then

```r
sample(c(rep(1, 56), rep(2, 24)))
# or
sample(rep(1:2, times=c(56, 24)))
```